# Laravel storage accessibility confusion

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble figuring out how Laravel's storage works since there are two public folders and I am confused which people talk about when I read posts about it.

Just to put a context, I have an app where I want to store images just for logged in users. I get the fact that public folder allows everybody too see images, I don't want that. There are two folders named public though which are :

[image: Hiarchy]

I'm quite sure public is just for css/js/index.php etc. and storage/app/public is the folder where stored files are publicly accessible. I am, however, not a 100% sure.

If I want to have private images for logged in users, is it correct having created the clients folder in the storage/app/ folder?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, Laravel aims for both of them to be the same. And it is explained at great extend in the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Even is the storage folder is indeed protected, when you run the command `php artisan storage:link` you will create a symbolic link between `public/storage` and `storage/app/public`.

All the items available in `storage/app/public` will then be available in `public/storage` and accessible from the outside.

If you want to prevent public access, then you need to use the `local` driver (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-local-driver) and it will be stored securely within your application. For example:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('FOLDERNAME/file.txt', 'Contents');
```

won't be accessible from the outside.

Comment: If I understand well, the two files linked by red lines are the same if I use the link. So to hide files to connected users I have to use storage/app/FOLDERNAME ?

Comment: Very nice thanks, do you know if "storeAs" achieves the same?

Comment: `storeAs()` is a method just like `put()` which lay on top of the `disk` architecture